# how to chose when to use decimal number in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my code to get an amount --

```
<xsl:variable name= "A" select="/abc/amount" />
<xsl:variable-of select="@A"/>
```

value of A is coming as 100.

my requirement is to remove that decimal " . "
so i used

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($A,'.')" />
```

it worked
but let assume the amount value is 100.12

so i have to use display the value with decimal when there is value after ' . '

please let me know how i can use `<xsl:choose><xsl:when>`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the result you want in each case? And what exactly is the value of $A in the first example? Is it `100.` (a number with a decimal separator, with no digits following the separator)?

Comment: Hi thank you i figure it out

Comment: @MariaDeleva Your approach would fail when `$A` is an integer.

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="A" select="/abc/amount" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$A" >
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($A),'#.#######')"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($A, '.')" />
</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(/abc/amount)"/>
```

which converts to a number and then does default numeric formatting, which as far as I can see should meet your requirements. If not, you need to be more precise about your requirements, but you can probably get what you want using the `format-number()` function.